# replace values of variable to strings in MatLab

Tags: sql, oracle, matlab

I want to build a Oracle SQL string with variables passed from outside a function. Here is what I have:

```
function(start_date, price_type)

price_type = [' ''PJM LMP'' ', ',' , ' ''MISO LMP'' ']

start_date = '01-Jan-2014';

query = ['select * from price_table where PRICE_TYPE in (''PJM LMP'', ''MISO LMP'') and  hour > to_date(''01-Jun-2014'', ''dd-mon-yyyy'') '];
```

I want to replace the value in `price_type` and `start_date` to the query, but cannot figure out how to deal with the quotation marks.

Comment: have you looked at [sprintf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html)?

Comment: `query = sprintf('select * from table where PRICE_TYPE in (%s) and hour > to_date('%s', ''dd-mon-yyyy'') ',price_type,start_date);` and then make sure both `price_type` and `start_date` begin and end with a `'`

Comment: thanks. that works. But I would still like to see a solution without requiring me to have a ' around my string. As you can know I lose '  when doing it this way: >> start_date = '01-Jan-2014'
start_date =
01-Jan-2014

Comment: Just add it to the format string in sprintf, this would require you to split price types into two variables. `query = sprintf('select * from table where PRICE_TYPE in ('%s','%s') and hour > to_date('%s', ''dd-mon-yyyy'') ',price_type1,price_type2,start_date);`

Answer (score 0):

Raab70, 
thanks. Here is what I figured out eventually. It works with any number of types.

```
type_str = sprintf(' ''%s'' ', char(type_cell(1)));
for i_type =2 : length(type_cell)
    type_str= sprintf(' %s , ''%s'' ', type_str, char(type_cell(i_type)));
end
query = sprintf('select * from table where PRICE_TYPE in (%s) and hour >= to_date(''%s'', ''dd-mon-yyyy'') and hour < to_date(''%s'', ''dd-mon-yyyy'')', type_str, start_date, end_date);
```